Unable to request Relation field
I seem to be having issues trying to request the relation field from the API.
export async function fetchContent(params) {
    const reqOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`
        }
    };
    const request = await fetch(`${base}/api/guides?populate=*${params}`, reqOptions);
    const response = await request.json();
    return response;    
}


const blogs = await fetchContent(`&filters[Slug][$eq]=${params.slug}`);

I have also tried to set the permission on both Authenticated and Public to "find" & "findOne".
Any info on this would be great thanks!

this call is made on frontend or backend?

@Frankusky This request is made on the frontend.

@McMaco Please do not add deprecated tags to postings. Please read [tag:api] where it says "Do not use"

I think that the issue is that in nextjs, you must prepend NEXT_PUBLIC_ on your environment variables to expose them to the frontend as stated here

Bundle environment variables for the browser by prefixing with NEXT_PUBLIC_

So in your env file you should have something like
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN=123456ASDFG

And then in your file you should retrieve it as
Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TOKEN}`

